# SQL LIKE using special character

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

How do I get a query that brings me word that contains or does not the special character?
Eg, I have this data: "NÃO" and if I search by typing "NAO", you should return this information to me. And the converse too, if I have: "ANTONIO" and I write "ANTÓNIO," ANTÓNIO should return to me.
I use this code but it does not work:

```
SELECT * FROM PESSOA WHERE NOME like '%'+ @PROCURAR + '%'
```

Comment: "NÃO" and "NAO" are different characters

Comment: Give this a try, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461522/how-do-i-perform-an-accent-insensitive-compare-e-with-è-é-ê-and-ë-in-sql-ser

Comment: A bit of a hack, but you could compare to `REPLACE(NOME, 'Ã', 'A')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accent Sensitive and Accent Insensitive searching can be don by using `Latin1_general_CI_AI`

ie, **ÃNTONIO** and **ANTONIO** are the same if Accent Insensitive.

In the below query `Latin1_general_CI_AI` can be break down into the following parts.

- `latin1` makes the server treat strings using charset latin 1, basically ascii.
- **CI** specifies case-insensitive, so "ABC" equals to "abc".
- **AI** specifies accent-insensitive,so 'ü' equals to 'u'.

Your **query** should be as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE field_name COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI Like '%ANTONIO%' COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI
```

Expected **Result** is as follows:

```
 Id  name
 1  ÃNTONIO 
 2  ANTÓNIO 
 3  ANTONIO 
 4  ANTÓNIÓ
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM PESSOA 
WHERE NOME COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI Like '%'+ @PROCURAR + '%' 
COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
```

for please visit Latin1_General_CI_AI

[in sql server, what is: Latin1_General_CI_AI versus Latin1_General_CI_AS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292830/in-sql-server-what-is-latin1-general-ci-ai-versus-latin1-general-ci-as)

see also 
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4395/understanding-the-collate-databasedefault-clause-in-sql-server/